# Unity iOS ImagePicker freeze

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine

I use ImagePicker in my unity project, but while edititng image it's frozen sometimes. I got that it's becouse of the next line in UnityAppController:

```
while (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kTrackingRunLoopMode, kInputProcessingTime, TRUE) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource)
```

If I comment this line while picking everything is OK. But I can't understant why this happens. Could somebody explain this pls?

Here is my temporary "solution" for this issue:

```
- (void)repaintDisplayLink
{
    [_displayLink setPaused: YES];
    {
        static const CFStringRef kTrackingRunLoopMode = CFStringRef(UITrackingRunLoopMode);
        if (![EtceteraManager picking])
        {
            while (CFRunLoopRunInMode(kTrackingRunLoopMode, kInputProcessingTime, TRUE) == kCFRunLoopRunHandledSource)
                ;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591701/uiimagepickercontroller-occasionally-freezing-up

This is the question about the same issue. (We're two developers working on the same product, @Zura wasn't aware I already asked about it).